# How do I prove that an algebraic system is a particular algebraic system?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I can build up a table of operations for $Z_n$ for multiplication and addition, but how do I prove that this either field, group or ring in abstract algebra? I know the laws of field, ring and group - but how do I apply it to table?

Answer (score 0):

It is tedious to prove such things from a table, and in the case of $\Bbb Z_n$, where you have $n^3$ products/sums to check for associativity, if $n$ is large, this may well take you a *very* long time.

One tool that mathematicians use to prove these sorts of things are theorems involving *homomorphisms*. For example, if $f: G \to H$ is a homomorphism of groups, then it is a theorem that $\text{im }f = f(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$. A special case is worth mentioning here: when $f$ is *surjective*, in which case we say $H$ is a *homomorphic image of* $G$. It is a central theorem of group theory that homomorphic images of a group $G$ correspond to (each one is isomorphic to) quotient groups of $G$.

In your case, this boils down to showing $\Bbb Z_n$ is a quotient group (and actually, a quotient ring) of $\Bbb Z$. The homomorphism (for both groups or rings) is:

$k \mapsto k\ (\text{mod }n$).

With quotients, a lot of the axioms we get "for free", for example, if $f:G \to H$, and $G$ is a group, and $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$ for any $a,b,c \in G$, then for $x = f(a), y = f(b), z = f(c)$ we get:

$(xy)z = (f(a)f(b))f(c) = f(ab)f(c) = f((ab)c) = f(a(bc)) = f(a)f(bc) = f(a)(f(b)f(c)) = x(yz)$,

so associativity holds in $f(G)$, and we don't have to "re-prove" it.

So a lot of the axioms that have to be verified are "inherited" in $\Bbb Z_n$ from similar properties in the integers, as long as we know that reducing "mod $n$" *respects addition and multiplication* (this is another way of stating the homomorphic properties).

Proving whether or not $\Bbb Z_n$ is a field, is a subtler question (the answer depends on $n$). The "slickest proofs" (and also the hardest to grasp naively) use properties of *ideals* (these are the things we "quotient by" in rings). Now, if you have a table, you can go through the columns one by one (excepting the $0$ column, of course), and see whether or not $1$ (the multiplicative identity) occurs in each column (for a non-commutative ring, you have to check the rows, too). But this isn't a very efficient way of checking, and doesn't give insight into which $\Bbb Z_n$ are fields, in general.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds for you as a silly question, but I do not understand much of this theorems: how do I know if a ring is commutative or not?

Comment: If $ab = ba$. If you have a Cayley table, a commutative binary operation will be symmetric about the main diagonal (top/left to bottom/right). And no, it's not a silly question. I understand you may not know much about homomorphisms-I urge you to explore them, they will save you time and effort in the long run.

Comment: So all of my tables are commutative? Even this with addition? But addition is not multiplication. Is addition commutative?(it does not matter if I add 4+3 or 3+4) +(I have got modulo[(+)4 - plus in circle). 

Please ;( - in simple language - just like for idiot: how do I recognize group, field and ring?

Comment: Yes, it is true that $\Bbb Z_n$ has both commutative addition *and* multiplication-it "inherits" these properties from the integers.